# Wrap an html element conditionally in JSTL

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I need to wrap an html element conditionally in JSTL.

For example I need to convert a portion of text into a link based on a condition, something like below.

```
<c:if test="${not empty link}">
    <a href='${link)" target="_blank">
</c:if>
    ${value}
<c:if test="${not empty value.link}">
    </a>
</c:if>
```

Obviously the above code is not valid. I am actually looking for some neat way to do this.

```
<c:wrap_if element="a" href="${link}" target="_blank">
    ${value}
</c:wrap_if>
```

Is there a tag available like that already. Should I write my own? Or is there a better and a more cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Why is your code not valid? Change the second `not empty value.link` to only be `not empty link`.

Comment: My code is not valid, as it not valid xml, not because I am using value.link.

Comment: I believe you are using the optimal solution already.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with such construction:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${not empty link}">
      <a href="${link}" target="_blank">${value}</a>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      ${value}
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: I am not much happy with this approach, primary because I have to repeat my logic of outputting value more than once. If ${value} is not as simple as that, it would be a real pain.

Comment: If you have non-simple ${value} you can calculate it before and set to variable: <c:set var="preparedValue" value="${your-logic}" />.

Comment: Maybe it is better to generate a span with value in that case. And if ${not empty link} assign special class to span. After that write small jquery code that will check spans with that class and wraps it with "a" element

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well -

```
    <c:set var="myHtml" value="${value}" />
    <c:if test="${not empty link}">
      <c:set var="myHtml" value="<a href='${link)' target='_blank'>${value}</a>" />
    </c:if>
    ${myHtml}
```